# keycloak + mysql configuration

Tags: mysql, jdbc, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a local database that I want to configure keycloak , Im running a docker container , so I changed the keycloak.conf file and I have set these proprities :
the credentials of the database are correct

- db=mysql
- db-username=root
- db-password=
- db-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crowd_up_auth

when I try to run the container , I get these errors in the log

```
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2023-08-18 22:11:56,739 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 7583ms
2023-08-18 22:11:58,396 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
2023-08-18 22:12:00,555 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2023-08-18 22:12:00,776 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-08-18 22:12:00,777 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:416)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:128)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:113)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource.getXAConnection(MysqlXADataSource.java:52)
at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:232)
at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
... 18 more
2023-08-18 22:12:01,330 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-08-18 22:12:01,538 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2023-08-18 22:12:01,930 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2023-08-18 22:12:01,944 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-08-18 22:12:02,132 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2023-08-18 22:12:02,132 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2023-08-18 22:12:02,133 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-08-18 22:12:02,133 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-08-18 22:12:02,133 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Connection refused
2023-08-18 22:12:02,133 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

this is the keycloak.conf file

```
# Basic settings for running in production. Change accordingly before deploying the server.

# Database

# The database vendor.
#db=postgres

db=mysql
#db-url-host=localhost
#db-url-database=crowd_up_auth
#db-url-port=3306

# The username of the database user.
db-username=root

# The password of the database user.
db-password=

# The full database JDBC URL. If not provided, a default URL is set based on the selected database vendor.
db-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crowd_up_auth

# Observability

# If the server should expose healthcheck endpoints.
#health-enabled=true

# If the server should expose metrics endpoints.
#metrics-enabled=true

# HTTP

# The file path to a server certificate or certificate chain in PEM format.
#https-certificate-file=${kc.home.dir}conf/server.crt.pem

# The file path to a private key in PEM format.
#https-certificate-key-file=${kc.home.dir}conf/server.key.pem

# The proxy address forwarding mode if the server is behind a reverse proxy.
#proxy=reencrypt

# Do not attach route to cookies and rely on the session affinity capabilities from reverse proxy
#spi-sticky-session-encoder-infinispan-should-attach-route=false

# Hostname for the Keycloak server.
#hostname=http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: The errir messages mean that you uses the wrong host name / IP address or port number or mmysql is not running at all or something actively blocks the connection.

Comment: you are right , I tried to shutdown mysql and I got exactly the same error , does that mean that I have problem connecting the keycloak server to my local mysql , to clarify things mysql works fine with other applications with these exact same credentials